# Why model history and model outputHistory are always undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am new to ML and trying to use TensorFlow.js to train my program and predict output based on 2 inputs but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly, it is easy to explain using code so adding it below.

Code below is called once,

```
const hiddenLayer = tf.layers.dense({
    units: 6,
    inputShape: [2],
    activation: 'sigmoid',
    kernelInitializer: 'leCunNormal',
    useBias: true,
    biasInitializer: 'randomNormal',
});
const outputLayer = tf.layers.dense({ units: 1 });
this.someModel = tf.sequential(); 
this.someModel.add(hiddenLayer);
this.someModel.add(outputLayer);
this.someModel.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd' });
```

Code below is called once per second to train model and to predict next output,

```
const  h = this.trainModel();
var inputs = [input1, input2]; 

tf.tidy(() => {
  const outputs = this.someModel.predict(tf.tensor2d([ inputs ]));
  outputs.data().then(output => {
    if (output > 0.5) {
        // do some action     
    }
  });
});

async trainModel() {
console.log("this.someModel.history " + this.someModel.history)
console.log("this.someModel.outputHistory " + this.someModel.outputHistory)

return await this.someModel.fit(tf.tensor2d(this.someModel.history),        tf.tensor1d(this.someModel.outputHistory), {
  shuffle: true,
});
}
```

this.someModel.history and this.someModel.outputHistory are always printing following,

```
this.someModel.history undefined
this.someModel.outputHistory undefined
```

And I am getting following error because they are undefined,

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: The input to the tensor constructor must
>   be a non-null value.

***What am I doing wrong ? I am not sure why I even need model.fit method, I guess predict function will build up a model for my program in memory and then predict based on this ***

Comment: is there any suggestion for me plz?

Comment: Could you please check the value of input before passing it to the predict function ?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that you're passing to the tensor constructor is null. That's the reason why you're getting the error.

`tf.model` does not have a `history` property. The `history` of the training is returned by the `fit` method. Therefore, if you want to get the history, you can proceed this way:

```
history = await this.someModel.fit(tf.zeros([1, 3]) , tf.zeros([1, 1]), {
  shuffle: true,
});
// then you can do whatever you want with the history
```

However it is not clear what you want to do by creating a 1d tensor of `history`. `history` is an object and cannot be used to create a tensor whose constructor's parameter is an array

To train or fit your model, you need to supply values that you have or that you create yourself. Those values are not returned by the model itself as you think by using `this.someModel.history`, `this.someModel.outputHistory`

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering but I am not sure what arrayInput and anotherArrayInput will be in my scenario

Comment: @user2262511 they are the data you want to fit your model with. I edited the answer by using fake data created wih `tf.zeros`

Comment: Thank you, maybe I sound stupid but I don't have any data in hand to provide and to train model, what I am trying to do is to train and predict at same time, e.g. look at all previous or last let say 100 inputs and output to predict the next move, so with each second I will have new input1, input2 which I want to give to model and let model predict the next move, am I making sense at all ? how do I convert these input1 and input2 into tensors and provide it to fit function, thanks again

Comment: in other words, I want model to train itself based on historic data it already used to predict the output

Comment: You can use a reinforcement learning algorithm or a recurrent neural network. You can see examples in tfjs gallery on github on how to do the prediction recursively. As for the reason why your history is undefined, it was given in my answer.

Comment: +1, it seems like my code is far far away from where I need to be, maybe because I am too new to all this